# How can i display an emoji in the Toolbar title?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, emoji

I have an emoji(ex: "\U0001F610") and I'd like to display it in the toolbar title. It works well in a TextView, but it doesn't seem to work for the toolbar. Can you give me any advice on how to do it properly?

Comment: ((YourActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("\U0001F610");

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar.Title = "\uD83D\uDE03";
```

[image]

```
ActionBar.Title = "\uD83D\uDE03" + "\uD83D\uDE0F" + "\uD83D\uDE10";
```

[image]